# How to enter this code to a method " catch Exception MsgBox() " in C#

Tags: c#, methods

**Hello every buddy,
I am beginner at C#** 
................................

### And I hope that you will help me with this code To enter in the method :

An example of the code :

```
private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int y = 2;
        int n = 0;
        int x = y / n;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        StackTrace st = new StackTrace(ex, true);

        //Get the first stack frame
        StackFrame frame = st.GetFrame(0);

        //Get the file name
        string fileName = frame.GetFileName();

        //Get the method name
        string methodName = frame.GetMethod().Name;

        //Get the line number from the stack frame
        int line = frame.GetFileLineNumber();

        //Get the column number
        int col = frame.GetFileColumnNumber();


        MessageBox.Show("Error code : " + 
            "\n" + ex.Message + 
            "\n-----------------------" + 
            "\nThe line and column : " + 
            "\n Line is :" + line.ToString() + 
            "\n Column is " + col.ToString() + 
            "\n" + "-----------------------" + 
            "\n Method Name : " + 
            "\n" + methodName + 
            "\n" + "-----------------------" + 
            "\n file Name Path : " + 
            "\n" + fileName);
    }
}
```

I want to enter the code:

```
StackTrace st = new StackTrace(ex, true);  

//Get the first stack frame
StackFrame frame = st.GetFrame(0);

//Get the file name
string fileName = frame.GetFileName();

//Get the method name
string methodName = frame.GetMethod().Name;

//Get the line number from the stack frame
int line = frame.GetFileLineNumber();

//Get the column number
int col = frame.GetFileColumnNumber();

MessageBox.Show("Error code : " + 
    "\n" + ex.Message + 
    "\n-----------------------" + 
    "\nThe line and column : " + 
    "\n Line is :" + line.ToString() + 
    "\n Column is " + col.ToString() + 
    "\n" + "-----------------------" + 
    "\n Method Name : " + 
    "\n" + methodName + 
    "\n" + "-----------------------" + 
    "\n file Name Path : " + 
    "\n" + fileName);
```

To method msgBoxME() :

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int y = 2;
        int n = 0;
        int x = y / n;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        CLASS.msgBox m = new CLASS.msgBox();
        m.msgBoxME(); // this is the method Required

    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: What is your exact problem? Is it something you are unable to access msgBocME()? What is error?

Comment: The answer is the solution in the following

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract this to method:

```
private static void ShowException(Exception ex)
{
    StackTrace st = new StackTrace(ex, true);

    //Get the first stack frame
    StackFrame frame = st.GetFrame(0);

    //Get the file name
    string fileName = frame.GetFileName();

    //Get the method name
    string methodName = frame.GetMethod().Name;

    //Get the line number from the stack frame
    int line = frame.GetFileLineNumber();

    //Get the column number
    int col = frame.GetFileColumnNumber();


    MessageBox.Show("Error code : " +
        "\n" + ex.Message +
        "\n-----------------------" +
        "\nThe line and column : " +
        "\n Line is :" + line.ToString() +
        "\n Column is " + col.ToString() +
        "\n" + "-----------------------" +
        "\n Method Name : " +
        "\n" + methodName +
        "\n" + "-----------------------" +
        "\n file Name Path : " +
        "\n" + fileName);
}
```

And call this new method inside of catch'es:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int y = 2;
        int n = 0;
        int x = y / n;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        CLASS.msgBox m = new CLASS.msgBox();
        m.ShowException(ex); // this is the method Required

    }
}
```

Or even use globally in whole application domain Unhandled exception handler:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += 
    (s, e) => ShowException(e.ExceptionObject);
```

Comment: This is a logical solution , Please vote up me